# How to deserialize json coming from dynamodb stream

Tags: python, json

```
event = event = {'Records': [{'eventID': '2339bc590c21035b84f8cc602b12c1d2', 'eventName': 'INSERT', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1595908037.0, 'Keys': {'id': {'S': '9'}}, 'NewImage': {'last_name': {'S': 'Hus'}, 'id': {'S': '9'}, 'age': {'S': '95'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '3100000000035684810908', 'SizeBytes': 23, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:656441365658:table/glossary/stream/2020-07-28T00:26:55.462'}, {'eventID': 'bbd4073256ef3182b3c00f13ead09501', 'eventName': 'MODIFY', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1595908037.0, 'Keys': {'id': {'S': '2'}}, 'NewImage': {'last_name': {'S': 'JJ'}, 'id': {'S': '2'}, 'age': {'S': '5'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '3200000000035684810954', 'SizeBytes': 21, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:656441365658:table/glossary/stream/2020-07-28T00:26:55.462'}, {'eventID': 'a9c90c0c4a5a4b64d0314c4557e94e28', 'eventName': 'INSERT', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1595908037.0, 'Keys': {'id': {'S': '10'}}, 'NewImage': {'last_name': {'S': 'Hus'}, 'id': {'S': '10'}, 'age': {'S': '95'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '3300000000035684810956', 'SizeBytes': 25, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:656441365658:table/glossary/stream/2020-07-28T00:26:55.462'}, {'eventID': '288f4a424992e5917af0350b53f754dc', 'eventName': 'MODIFY', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1595908037.0, 'Keys': {'id': {'S': '1'}}, 'NewImage': {'last_name': {'S': 'V'}, 'id': {'S': '1'}, 'age': {'S': '2'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '3400000000035684810957', 'SizeBytes': 20, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:656441365658:table/glossary/stream/2020-07-28T00:26:55.462'}]}
```

The above one coming from dynamodb stream. I need to extract the some value from above

Code is below nothing is returning

```
def deserialize(event):
    data = {}
    data["M"] = event
    return extract_some(data)
def extract_some(event):
    for key, value in list(event.items()):
        if (key == "NULL"):
            return None
        if (key == "S" or key == "BOOL"):
            return value

for record in event['Records']:
    doc =  deserialise(record['dynamodb']['NewImage'])
    print (doc)
```

Expected Out

```
{'last_name': 'Hus', 'id': '9', 'age': '95'}
{'last_name': 'JJ', 'id': '2', 'age': '5'}
{'last_name': 'Hus', 'id': '10', 'age': '95'}
{'last_name': 'V', 'id': '1', 'age': '2'}
```

Comment: In the `for` loop you misspelled `deserialise` and what's `node` ? where do you declare it ? or what is it supposed to be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
from pprint import pprint

result = []
for r in event['Records']:
    tmp = {}

    for k, v in r['dynamodb']['NewImage'].items():
        if "S" in v.keys() or "BOOL" in v.keys():
            tmp[k] = v.get('S', v.get('BOOL', False))
        elif 'NULL' in v:
            tmp[k] = None

    result.append(tmp)
    
pprint(result)
```

---

```
[{'age': '95', 'id': '9', 'last_name': 'Hus'},
 {'age': '5', 'id': '2', 'last_name': 'JJ'},
 {'age': '95', 'id': '10', 'last_name': 'Hus'},
 {'age': '2', 'id': '1', 'last_name': 'V'}]
```

Comment: what is  "BOOL" in v.keys(), and what is `v.get('BOOL', False)`

Comment: in first case checking if given key exits in dict, in second case check if key exists if not return default value for that key.

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618932/how-to-read-content-from-the-s3-bucket-as-url