# How to read content from the s3 bucket as url

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have s3 bucket url is below

s3_filename is `s3://xx/xx/y/z/ion.csv`

if its is bucket i can read like below code

```
def read_s3(bucket, key):
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
        return df
```

Comment: are you having any problem with your code?

Comment: @deadshot my code will read from usng bucket name not with the URL

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be using Pandas, please note that it actually uses `s3fs` under the cover. So, if your install is relatively recent and standard, you may directly do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(s3_path)
```

If you have some specific config for your bucket, for example special credentials, KMS encryption, etc., you may use an explicitly configured `s3fs` filesystem, for example:

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(
    key=my_aws_access_key_id,
    secret=my_aws_secret_access_key,
    s3_additional_kwargs={
            'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms',
            'SSEKMSKeyId': my_kms_key,
    },
)
# note: KMS encryption only used when writing; when reading, it is automatic if you have access

with fs.open(s3_path, 'r') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)

# here we write the same df at a different location, making sure
# it is using my_kms_key:
with fs.open(out_s3_path, 'w') as f:
    df.to_csv(f)
```

That said, if you are really interested to deal yourself with getting the object, and the question is just about how to remove a potential `s3://` prefix and then split `bucket/key`, you could simply use:

```
bucket, key = re.sub(r'^s3://', '', s3_path).split('/', 1)
```

But that may miss more general cases and conventions handled by systems such as [awscli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) or the very [s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) referenced above.

For more generality, you can take a look at how they do this in `awscli`. In general, doing so often provides a good indication of whether or not some functionality may already be built in `boto3` or `botocore`. In this case however, it would appear not (looking at a local clone of release-1.18.126). They simply do this from first principles: see `awscli.customizations.s3.utils.split_s3_bucket_key` as it is implemented [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/fc131df33f70d53b46c35e451824b4f32b6fe9b4/awscli/customizations/s3/utils.py#L199).

From the regex that is eventually used in that code, you can infer that the kind of cases `awscli` allows for `s3_path` is quite diverse indeed:

```
_S3_ACCESSPOINT_TO_BUCKET_KEY_REGEX = re.compile(
    r'^(?P<bucket>arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[:/][^/]+)/?'
    r'(?P<key>.*)$'
)
```